# Updating large amount of documents in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am working on solution to this problem:

I have got a large collection of entries, that regularly I have to update from the other database. I am using express.js with mongodb. The schedule of updating starts everyday at 1am. I fetch external data, compare to currently existing and update all entries in our databse.

The process looks like:
1) Fetch internal and external data
2) Combine them together (past entries from our database, future entries from the other database)
3) Delete all records in our database
4) InsertMany - records that the program just combined.

So as you can see it's a quite risky task. If any error would occur between deleting and inserting data in the collection, we lose all data.

And there are my questions:

1) Is there any effective way of reverting data that has been just deleted in mongo? Or keep them on hold and insert back on its place, if any error occurs?

2) Is there any other effective way of updating few hundreds/thousands of documents apart from deleteMany -> insertMany // updateOne on each document?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: for your case I suggest to use Bulk() here the documentation : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk/

Comment: can I ask you why don't you use update one by one? In this case, you will have old data or newly updated data. No risk of data loss. can I know the specific rreason behind fetching all data then creating new object, then delete old and add new data. I bet updating one by one will take less time then the one you are doing now.

Comment: If there is something in common between your old and new data, then you don't even need to fetch data directly assign update data, that's it.

Comment: @SureshShetiar, I am getting only the most recent data, while at the same time I need to keep past information too. That's why I am fetching all data at once, do the comparision and toss out data I don't need. It's quite a rough solution, I know. To be fair I was afraid that single update one by one would be too slow. The reason why I chosen to bulk delete/insert it is that, I had to update data preferably in the shortest possible time to allow other functionalities use the most recent data ASAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to your set of operation could be:

1. fetch external data
2. add external data in to a new
   database/collection
3. merge the data together with an aggeration
   query using $merge
   (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/)

That way you wouldn't have to delete all your data and could possibly end up with data loss.